# EFcore One Way Navigation of 1:n Navigation without modifying target table

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, foreign-keys, relationship

Assume I had the following class model:

```
[Table(nameof(Expense), Schema = "Cars")]
public class Expense
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Purpose { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public double Amount { get; set; }
}

[Table(nameof(Car), Schema = "Cars")]
public class Car
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Model { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string VIN { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public IList<Expense> Expenses { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public IList<Repair> Repairs { get; set; }
}

[Table(nameof(Repair), Schema = "Cars")]
public class Repair
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Failure { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime Finished { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public IList<Expense> Expenses { get; set; }
}
```

Now I am trying to use that code to create data tables for EFcore 6/7 and end up with a table `Expense` holding columns for `CarId` and `RepairId`.

As you can probably see, `Expense` is a rather general table that could be an expense for anything thus it should not be bound to or reference neither `Car` nor `Repair`.

In SQL naturally I would create relation tables that allow me to define the relation between `Car` and `Expense` as well as `Repair` and `Expense`.

The classes for those relation tables would look something like this:

```
[Table(nameof(CarExpense), Schema = "Cars")]
public class CarExpense
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Car Car { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Expense Cost { get; set; }
}

[Table(nameof(RepairExpense), Schema = "Cars")]
public class RepairExpense
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Repair Repair { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Expense Cost { get; set; }
}
```

Having defined these classes I would go on using fluent API to define the navigation trying to avoid the generation of unwanted columns in the `Expenses` table.

For this I'd start with defining a type configuration that looks somewhat like this:

```
public class ExpenseTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Expense>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Expense> builder)
    {
        builder.Property<IList<CarExpense>>("CarExpenses");
        builder.HasMany<Car>("CarExpenses").WithMany(x => x.Expenses)
            .UsingEntity<CarExpense>(
                ce => ce
                    .HasOne(x => x.Car)
                    .WithMany(),
                ce => ce.HasOne(x => x.Cost).WithMany(),
                i => i.HasKey(x => x.Id));
    }
}
```

This way I still end up with a table `Expense` that has `CarId` and `RepairId` definied.
Fluent API calls for Repair-Navigation were omitted for clarity and simplicity.

Some things I'd like to point out in advance:

- The relation is declared as m:n for various reasons althoug it should be 1:n

  - one `Car` has many `Expense`s, one `Expense` belongs to exactly one `Car` (or `Repair`), but
  - EFcore does not allow me `UsingEntity` when there is a 1:n relation
  - EFcore will always create `CarId` when there is a 1:n relation
  - I want to navigate from `Car` to `Expense` directly and not use the relationtable

    - e.g `Car.Expenses` instead of `Car.CarExpenses.Expenses`
  - I do not want to navigate from `Expense` to `Car` or `Repair` because I really don't need to
  - I don't want to have **any** reference in `Expense` to whatever type is using `Expense` as `Expense` could be used from anywhere and this should not affect the `Expense` table or type at all. That's what the relation tables or classes are supposed to be for.

Is there anything I can do to get what I try to achieve?